# compilation fails - program database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors

When I try to compile, I get this warning:

`Warning    8   warning : The process cannot access the file 'C:\PROGRAMDATA\BROWSER MANAGER\2.2.565.25\{16CDFF19-861D-48E3-A751-D99A27784753}\BROWSEMNGR.SETTINGS' because it is being used by another process.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppClean.targets`

followed by this error:
`Error  8   error C1033: cannot open program database ''`

I already tried uninstlaling and installing the VS 2010 but the problem does not seem to go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem doing these steps:

http://www.explosiveknowledge.net/main/2012/08/19/browsemngr/

And I was executing devenv.exe in compatibility with Windows XP, remove that. I also changed from `use` to `create` in the precompiled header menu options in my project.

Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** It's possible that two projects in the solution are writing their outputs to the same directory (e.g. 'xxx\debug'). If the maximum number of parallel project builds setting in Tools - Options, Projects and Solutions - Build and Run is set to a value greater than 1, this means that two compiler threads could be trying to access the same files simultaneously, resulting in a file sharing conflict.

**Solution:**
Check your project's settings and make sure no two projects are using the same directory for output, target or any kind of intermediate files. Or set the maximum number of parallel project builds setting to 1 for a quick workaround. I experienced this very problem while using the VS project files that came with the CLAPACK library.

Comment: The number of parallel builds was indeed over 1. I changed it back to 1 but it did not work, compilation still fails. Changed all the output directories from that project to desktop, still same error. I tried another project - in another directory - which is showing error `C1033` aswell, but another one poped up: `C2858`. If it is happening with any projects, maybe my VS environment is messed up?If yes, what should I do to fix it?